# Extjs grid scroll fix needed

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 4.2

Here is the code that  i am working on it

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: {
        'items': [{
            "name": "Lisa",
            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-111-1224"
        }, {
            "name": "Bart",
            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1234"
        }, {
            "name": "Homer",
            "email": "home@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244"
        }, {
            "name": "Marge",
            "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1254"
        }]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [ {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            selectOnFocus: true,
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    },{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        editor: 'textfield'
    }],
    selModel: {},
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 900,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

specifically in ie 11, when i click on the name  it jumps to first column.

Waiting for help. Thank you. Goog Luck

Comment: please recreate your problem using jsfiddle to increase your chance of an answer, like here http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/vdazU/

Comment: Use http://fiddle.sencha.com to describe your problem. It's very helpful for us.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is fixed in the 4.2.2 Release.

4.2.1
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pga 
4.2.2
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pgc

Comment: where can i get 4.2.2. can you please post the ext-all.js url

Comment: I wasn't able to find at official site. But finally I found it at sencha forum.
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273860-why-i-can-not-down-ExtJs-4.2.2